# Find basis and degree for splitting field of degree 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

Problem: Let $K= \mathbb{Q}$ and $f= X^3-3$. Find basis , splitting field and degree of splitting field over $K$ for $f$.

My attempt: $X^3-3$ has 3 roots, $\sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt[3]{3} \omega, \sqrt[3]{3}\omega^2$.

Hence $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt{-3})$ is a splitting field for $f$ over $K$.

By tower's law, $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb{Q}|=6$.

Therefore, $\{ 1, \sqrt[3]{3}$, $\sqrt[3]{3^2}, \omega, \sqrt[3]{3}\omega, \sqrt[3]{3^2}\omega^2 \}$ is a basis.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me, although some of the proofs are missing (e.g. you need to show that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]3, \sqrt{-3})/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]3)$ is a quadratic extension etc.)

Comment: @WhatsUp Indeed, though this follows from the fact that  $\sqrt{-3}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$

Comment: @WhatsUp these are problems i'm thinking of as extra practice, so I don't have solutions and that is why I keep asking here

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that's not a basis, because $$\sqrt[3]{3}+\omega\sqrt[3]{3}+\omega^2\sqrt[3]{3}=0$$

Comment: @Servaes I edited

Answer (score 1):

In fact, if we assume $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ such that
$$[KL:L]=[L:\mathbb{Q}],$$
then $$KL=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)=span_{\mathbb{Q}}<\alpha^i\beta^j:0\le i\le n-1,0\le j\le m-1>,$$
where $n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ and $m=[L:\mathbb{Q}]$.
Now, we need to prove that $w\notin \mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{3}})$, and it is clear.